# How do you change the default font color for all text in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This only changed it for chart titles, but left axis titles the default color:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set each text property separately, e.g.:

```
COLOR = 'blue'
mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = COLOR
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = COLOR
mpl.rcParams['xtick.color'] = COLOR
mpl.rcParams['ytick.color'] = COLOR
```

The full list of params is at https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html.

Comment: Thanks works for me. Background in jupyter to dark...

Answer (score 8):

To set the label color in the rcParams as well use

```
text.color: blue
axes.labelcolor: blue
```

or, from within the script

```
mpl.rcParams.update({'text.color' : "blue",
                     'axes.labelcolor' : "blue"})
```